# Nearest Neighbor clustering python implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I wrote this code based on the pseudocode I found

```
C0 = [X[0]]
Clusters = [C0]
p=0
x=0
for i in range(1, len(X)):
  arr = np.array([euclidean(X[i], c) for sublist in Clusters for c in sublist])
  p = [c for sublist in Clusters for c in sublist]
  pnd= [p,arr]
  x= np.min(arr[np.nonzero(arr)])
  point = pnd[0][arr.tolist().index(x)]

  if x < 4:
    for list in Clusters:
      for cord in list:
        if point == Clusters[Clusters.index(list)][list.index(cord)]:
              Clusters[Clusters.index(list)].append(X[i])
  else:
    Clusters.append([X[i]])
```

it worked fine when I had 8 datapoints but now I have 300 and it fails at these 2 lines

```
if point == Clusters[Clusters.index(list)][list.index(cord)]:
              Clusters[Clusters.index(list)].append(X[i])
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is the psedocode i followed

```
Input: D = fx1; x2;    ; xng // A set of instances.
A // Adjacency matrix showing distance between instances
Output: A set of C clusters.
Method:
1: C1 = {x1};
2: C = {C1};
3: k = 1;
4: for i = 2 to n do
5:   find xm in some cluster Cm in C so that dis(xi ; xm) is the smallest;
6:   if dis(xi ; xm) t; threshold value then
7:      Cm = Cm union xi
8:   else
9:      k = k + 1;
10:     Ck = {xi};
11:     C = C union Ck ;
12:  end if
13: end for
```

I tried using any() but then i got the error in the body of the if statement then i realised any isnt useful in my case as it has to the specific cluster it was found in

edit: I added this line and it seems to be working but the code been running forever it was running for an hour so i stopped it and I'm not even sure this new line is correct

```
if np.equal(list,point).any():
              Clusters[np.where(np.equal(list,point).any()== True)[0][0]].append(X[i])
```

Comment: How many elements does `Clusters[Clusters.index(list)][list.index(cord)]` have when the error happens?

Comment: i did a print(i) and I got 11 so i'm guessing Clusters have 11 lists all containing 1 list